# Would scope would this variable(s) belong to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, scope

```
class Something:
    x = "hi"
    def func(self):
        k = "hi2"
```

In this piece of code, `x` as a `class attribute` and `k` as a variable. What scope (`local`, `enclosed`, `global`, `builtin`) would x belong to and what scope would k belong to?

Comment: The way this is worded it sounds suspiciously like homework (why should it be `builtin`?). Have you tried researching scopes in Python? Most tutorials have a section on those.

Comment: Just fixed the indentation. And this isnt homework, I know that the answer isn't `built in` or `global` scope, I just put that there so that I would get an answer that would answer what scope category the variables belong to, and not something like: this variable belongs to this functions scope, etc

Comment: Not within `func()`, but rather outside of the class

Answer (score 2):

You say you don't want an answer like "in the scope of the function" or "-- the class", but that would be the most precise answer. A scope like `local` is always relative to where you are.

If you are in the global scope, then only the class itself is in both the `local` and `global` scope (which are the same then), but neither of the variables are. You can access `x` via the class, but `k` will only be defined when the function is called.

If you are inside of `func`, then `k` and `self` are in the `local` scope, but `x` is in neither the `local` nor `global` scope. It is not in the enclosed scope either; it can not be accessed directly, as in `print(x)`, but only via the instance `self` or the class `Something`.

```
class Something:
    x = "hi"
    def func(self):
        k = "hi2"
        print(locals())    # contains k, self
        print(globals())   # contains Something
        print(k)           # works
        print(self.x)      # works
        print(Something.x) # works
        print(x)           # does not work

Something().func()
```

---

The case is different with nested functions. Here, variables defined in the outer functions are in the "enclosing scope", but may be promoted to the local scope by using them:

```
def f():
    a = []
    def g():
        b = None
        # a = []   # define a new a in local scope?
        # a.append(42)  # without above line, this changes enclosed a
        print(locals())  # only b, unless you use a here
    g()
    print(a)
f()
```

- if you leave the commented lines as they are, only `b` in in the inner local scope
- if you activate the `append` line, `a` from the enclosing scope is moved to the local scope and changed in both scopes
- if you activate both commented lines, a new `a` is defined in the local scope without changing the `a` in the enclosing scope

Comment: "but x is in neither the local nor global scope. It is not in the enclosed scope either" so a variable doesn't belong to any scope if it is declared just like that in a class (as a class attribute meaning outside any method apart of that class) ?

Comment: @DavidKolesanov I guess it's a matter of interpretation. The class is in the global scope, and the instance in the local scope, and you can access `x` via either of those. But you can not just use `x`, as in the last line. With an enclosing scope (as in nested functions) that would be possible.